# update on only one ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to do an update statement, but this update query have to update only one row. I need to know that the "id" or "key" appears only once.

```
update td
set td.t_ID = d.Document_ID 
from #t_documents td
join document d with (nolock)
on d.D_header = td.t_header_ID
and d.D_sequence = td.t_D_sequence 
where count(distinct d.Document_ID) = 1
```

how I do this query that check that the update was only done once

Comment: Add sample data and expected result.

Comment: will have to use a subquery on where clause. `where 1 = (select count() from <table> where id = td.id ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but give a go:

```
IF (
    SELECT count(DISTINCT d.Document_ID)
    from #t_documents td
    join document d with (nolock)
    on d.D_header = td.t_header_ID
    and d.D_sequence = td.t_D_sequence) = 1
BEGIN
    update td
    set td.t_ID = d.Document_ID 
    from #t_documents td
    join document d with (nolock)
    on d.D_header = td.t_header_ID
    and d.D_sequence = td.t_D_sequence 
END
```

or as Stephen pointed subquery(haven't tested this):

```
update td
set td.t_ID = d.Document_ID 
from #t_documents td
join document d with (nolock)
on d.D_header = td.t_header_ID
and d.D_sequence = td.t_D_sequence 
where (
    SELECT count(DISTINCT d.Document_ID)
    from #t_documents td
    join document d with (nolock)
    on d.D_header = td.t_header_ID
    and d.D_sequence = td.t_D_sequence) = 1
```

Comment: just pointing out that the first option will not work as expected.

Comment: the problem is I am not really sure what is "expected" in this question, but you may be right

Comment: the second one is more what I expected. Thank you

Comment: @sarikaya, are you getting correct update with 2nd script or this has to be modified as well?